# How to use SSIS of SQL Server 2014 on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm trying to use SSIS of SQL Server 2014, I already had SQL Server so I've followed some tutorials of how to add the SSIS functionality. I downloaded the  setup of SQL Server but SSIS is missing when I look for it.

I read on a previous post that it's because I'm downloading SQL Server express
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and that version doesn't have that feature.

But I've seen videos where they have the same link and to them do appear the SSIS when they're doing the same procedure.

**My question:** what can I do to use SSIS of SQL Server because I have Windows 7 and other versions as SQL Server 2016, 2017 need Windows 8 or newer, but I don't want to install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download SQL Server Developer Edition, if you are just planning to use it for development purposes. It is having SSIS coming with it.

SQL Server Developer Edition 2014 supports Windows 7. You can see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014)

The SQL Server Developer Edition 2014 download instructions are available in the [Stackoverflow post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102208/sql-server-developer-edition-2012-or-2014-download)

You need to install Sql Server Developer Tools-BI (SSDT-BI) to work on Integration Services Project. You can download SSDT from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017). Choose the one corresponding to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no link to download SQL Server Developer Edition 2014 (or at least I didn't found it), the only link I found there is for the Express edition

Comment: @VenkataramanR SSDT-BI only applies if using Visual Studio 2013. If the OP is using VS 2015+, then they can just download the SDK, which will install its own instance of VS2017. The OP will then need to target the package to the specific version of SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2017